# Difference between consecutive rows using multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Ive got some records about project timelines and would like to calculate the difference between the end of one project phase and the start of another, per project. I have tried using the LEAD function however cant find a way to use it for multiple columns.

taking project A as example:
find the difference (delay) between phase2 and phase 1 (end_date of phase1 and start date of phase 2),  and phase3 and phase2 (end date of phase2 and start_date of phase 3)

| project name | project_phase | start_date | end_date | delay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| project_A | phase 1 | 20-01-2021 | 23-01-2021 |  |
| project_A | phase 2 | 27-01-2021 | 10-02-2021 |  |
| project_A | phase 3 | 17-02-2021 | 26-02-2021 |  |
| project_B | phase 1 | 02-02-2021 | 05-03-2021 |  |
| project_B | phase 2 | 12-03-2021 | 15-04-2021 |  |
| project_B | phase 3 | 21-04-2021 | 26-05-2021 |  |

what ive tried:

```
select project_name, project_phase,start_date, end_date ,
lead(end_date - start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY project_phase ORDER BY start_date ) as delay
from projects
```

what this is givin me is the difference in dates between start and end dates of the same project_phase. what i would want is the difference between the end date of phase1 and the start date of phase 2

Comment: `LEAD` seems to be the right choice. What is the problem exactly? Please show your query.

Comment: @Serg made the edit.

Comment: `LEAD` and the other windowing functions apply only to the rows inside a single partition. If you want to compare partitions inside a single project you should use `PARTITION BY PROJECT_NAME` and order either by project phase or start date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided `end_date`and `start_date` are `timestamp`  `delay` will be an `interval`.

```
select project_name, project_phase, start_date, end_date,
    end_date - lead(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY project_name ORDER BY start_date ) as delay
from projects
```

Comment: `start_date - end_date`, because the start date of phase 2 comes after end date of phase 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view with the delays and left join the project data with the view.

```sql
create table "project log"
(
  "project name" text,
  "project phase" text,
  "start date" date,
  "end date" date
);

insert into "project log"
(
  "project name",
  "project phase",
  "start date",
  "end date"
)
values
('project_A', 'phase 1', '2021-01-20', '2021-01-23'),
('project_A', 'phase 2', '2021-01-27', '2021-02-10'),
('project_A', 'phase 3', '2021-02-17', '2021-02-26'),
('project_B', 'phase 1', '2021-02-02', '2021-03-05'),
('project_B', 'phase 2', '2021-03-12', '2021-04-15'),
('project_B', 'phase 3', '2021-04-21', '2021-05-26');

create view "project delay" as
select
  "project name",
  "project phase",
  "start date" - 
  (select "end date"
   from "project log"
   where
     "project name" = p."project name" and
     "project phase" = 'phase 1') "delay"
from
  "project log" p
where
  "project phase" = 'phase 2'
union
select
  "project name",
  "project phase",
  "start date" - 
  (select "end date"
   from "project log"
   where
     "project name" = p."project name" and
     "project phase" = 'phase 2') "delay"
from
  "project log" p
where
  "project phase" = 'phase 3';

select *
from
  "project log" left join
  "project delay" using ("project name", "project phase");
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kzowBhxgay6W7H5VafyHvz/0